# Jquery UI cancel button needs to be click twice to close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my jQuery UI dialog once I click the close button, on the next time when the dialog appears, the cancel button needs to be click twice to close.

http://jsfiddle.net/AvF8V/6/

The following line of code works fine if im not clicking the (X)close button.

```
 jQuery("#message1").remove();
```

Once I clicked the close button, the cancel button will works only when click twice.

What is the reason of this scenario and how can I avoid it?

Comment: may be there are two dialog boxes opening rather than one..

Comment: Did you check my fiddle? Im clearing the buttonpane when new dialog creates.

Comment: The approach used to set up the buttons seems kinda odd..

Comment: But i need to add it dynamically from a JSON structure. Can you please explain what makes it odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below javascript will create a div "#message1" even another div with the same id already exists.

```
Alert('dialog_message1','this is a test');
```

The close button of jQuery dialog will not remove the container from html by default.
So there will be two or more divs with the same id ('#message1'), the `jQuery("#message1").remove();` will only remove the first one.

You should

1. check the if there exists another element with the same id when creating  OR
2. Use `$(this).dialog('destroy').remove()` if you want to remove the dialog.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne Wang. I added a random number to the div id and it works.